# Magento Configurable Products - Uses different layout to product/view.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I successfully edited the product/view.phtml file so that the add-to-cart button appears in a different location on the page. This works fine for simple products, but for configurable products this change is being ignored and the button is in its default place.

I cant figure out what I need to edit to apply the same change for configurable products.

It would be a lot easier if configurable products had their own template file.

Essentially all Im trying to do is create a box at the top right of the product content page that has the add-to-cart inside it, and for this to show in the same position for all product types.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/different-template-for-configurable-products

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely what I want to do in theory. I've tried doing something like the following to force configurable products to use the view.phtml layout, but it doesn't work. Is this a laughable idea or can it be tweaked to work?:                                                                                                        <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
  <reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>

Answer (score 0):

Configurable product does have a custom template, look at template/catalog/product/type/configurable.phtml

Comment: I already looked there, and this is a blank file which says: @deprecated after 1.4.1.0 in favor of default.phtml. If you look in default.phtml file it just has a small bit of code relating to the product stock status.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask a different question - Ie; how can you force configurable products to use the same add-to-cart button layout as the simple products?